# Stored Procedures with arguments

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, stored-procedures

I can't make my stored procedure (SQL Server) run with NHibernate. I have following mapping:

```
<sql-query name="udp_MyStoredProc">
    <query-param name="Id" type="Int32" />
    <query-param name="Name" type="String" />
    <return-scalar column="ResId" type="Int32"/>
    EXEC udp_MyStoredProc @Id = :Id, 
        @Name = :Name    
</sql-query>
```

Within code:

```
IQuery query = _HibSession.GetNamedQuery("udp_MyStoredProc");
query.SetInt32("Id", id);
query.SetString("Name", name);
var res = query.List();
```

This results in following exception:

> `[SQL: EXEC udp_MyStoredProc @Id =
>   @p0, @Name = @p1] --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Procedure or function udp_MyStoredProc
>   has too many arguments specified.`

I don't know what's wrong with the arguments? I also [read](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article749-execute-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-using-nhibernate-.aspx) something about '?' as placeholders for the parameters, but I don't quite understand it.

Signature of the Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[udp_MyStoredProc]
(
    @Id int,
    @Name NVARCHAR(255)
)
AS
BEGIN  ... END
```

If I do something like this within Server Management Studio, it works:

```
EXEC udp_MyStoredProc  @Id = 30, @Name = 'test'
```

thx for any tipps.

sl3dg3

Comment: Can you show us the definition of your stored proc??

Comment: @ marc_s, sorry, I forgot --> updated.

Comment: I'm (no longer) really familiar with NHibernate - but I would think the `<return-scalar column="ResId" ...>` is the problem. What if you remove that one mapping fragment??

Comment: If you are returning the scalar , what is that ToList () doing there?

Comment: @marc_s, I already tested without the return-scalar, same result...

Comment: Is the space at the end of `[udp_MyStoredProc ]`, as posted here, accidental or is it really present in the actual procedure's name?

Comment: @ Andriy M, that was by accident --> corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you switch on debugging and actually check what the extra argument is. You should be able to see exactly which field is the problem. It may be enough to look at the generated SQL, or you may have to configure a [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/download.html) logger (log4net is the debugger that NHibernate uses internally).

To display the generated SQL in the console, add (or modify) the following property to your NHibernate config file inside the session-factory section:

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
<session-factory>
  ...
  ...
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
</session-factory>
```

EDIT: I can add more details on Log4Net if you need it :)

EDIT 2: Other things to check if you get this error

1. Your SP should only return a single value
2. The name of the column returned by your SP should be the same as the name of the column defined in your return-scalar mapping. You can cast the column, eg:

   SELECT *field to return* AS ResId

EDIT 3:

you could try changing your mapping file to:

```
 <sql-query name="udp_MyStoredProc">
     <return-scalar column="ResId" type="Int32"/>
     EXEC udp_MyStoredProc: ?, ?    
 </sql-query>
```

Comment: I have the log4net attached, and as I wrote earlier it really queries `EXEC udp_MyStoredProc @Id = @p0, @Name = @p1`. If I run this within the sql-query window (e.g.: `EXEC udp_copy_event @Id = 30, @Name = 'test'`), it just runs fine...

Comment: Ok, then your problem is with the "rehydration" of whatever entity is going to hold the data returned by the stored procedure. When you run the SP from within the query window, does it return a single value, multiple rows, or multiple columns?

Comment: Didn't think of that... I have something like `SELECT @FirstId, @SecondId` at the end of my Stored Procedure. Two integers (multiple columns, one row). I tested it without the select, still same result...

Comment: Ok, I think this is one of the most annoying errors that NHibernate generates. Is the SP is now fixed so it returns a single value?

Comment: I changed it now to `SELECT @FirstId` (if it's that what you mean), but still same result... (within the test before I omitted the select-statement completely, also negative)

Comment: your return-scalar column name will also need to match the name of the column actually returned by the SP. I would guess that it is defaulting the return-scalar to null / zero, and then doesn't know what to do with the other column. Try changing your SP from `SELECT @FirstId` to `SELECT @FirstId AS ResId` (i.e. force the column returned to have the correct name).

Comment: I did that, but no success. What is very odd: I decided to trivialize the SP, so I left the second argument away (also deleted it from the mapping). That way it works (though I don't get the two Ids from the select-statment, but thats another problem now). By the way, it doesn't matter if I use the scalars in the mapping or not, with one argument it simply works...

Comment: Ok, I have one more thing you can try that might help (see EDIT 3 in my original answer).

Comment: Thx for this idea (Edit 3) - but how am I supposed to pass the arguments within the c# - code? What I did: `query.SetParameter(0, id)`. But it leads to: `Not all named parameters have been set: [''] [EXEC udp_MyStoredProc: ?]` (I tried for now with only one parameter...)

Comment: WOW I'm so sorry, I figured it out: I fired the query from a UnitTest (and not from the project itself). As a matter of fact, the UnitTest has of course its own config-file with its own connection-string (actually something annoying), which pointed to a different database with a different version of the stored procedure :(  ... very embarassing! I learned nevertheless a lot thanks to your kind input. Thank you for your patience, I hope I can pay it back one day!

Comment: No problem at all, I'm glad I could help. :)